# Keep element vertically centered with negative top while resize window

Tags: html, css

I'm gonna try to make it simple.
I've a long rectangle with a negative top to hide most part of it.
I want to keep it vertically centered when I re-size the window.

This is it:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/kejswyu5/2/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the changes as below to make it vertically middle all the time, also by using this method you can have dynamic height(No fixed height).

```
#box{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:44vw;
  width:50px;
  height:800px;
  border-bottom:3px solid black;
  background-color:red;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just changing the value `transform: translateY(-100%)` I did it!
https://fiddle.jshell.net/kejswyu5/3/